# How can I suppress unwanted browser zooming when I use barcode scanner?

Tags: javascript, browser, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have an app for Goods Received which allows the user to scan a barcode and it then populates a page in a web browser.  However, it appears that if the '+' character appears in the barcode, it causes the browser to zoom.

For example, these barcodes cause the problem:
[image]

This barcode works correctly:

[image]

Has anyone come across this before, and if so, how can I circumvent this unwanted behaviour?  The scanners are heterogeneous (no particular make) and people use all sorts of browsers (I'm using Opera and Chrome).

Thanks

Comment: Does it depend on the functions of the hardware (platform/scanner) and software (library/configuration) you are using? It will be easier to get advice and answers if you add those detailed information.

Comment: As I said in my original post, it's all vanilla.  No particular make of scanner, simple javascript, no third party libraries.

Comment: For research and analysis, you need to provide specific information for problem reproduction. If no hardware, system, or source code information are provided, there is too much to guess and few people will look up or answer. Or maybe no one is there. For example, is it a hardware autofocus function?